# media player error (262, 0)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I keep on getting this error

```
11-19 15:53:38.438 18039-3846/com.radioafrica.music D/dalvikvm: threadid=46: exiting
11-19 15:53:38.439 18039-3846/com.radioafrica.music D/dalvikvm: threadid=46: bye!
11-19 15:53:38.502 18039-18039/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaPlayer: Don't notify duration to com.radioafrica.music!
11-19 15:53:38.562 18039-18039/com.radioafrica.music D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x65dd2f78>
11-19 15:53:38.571 18039-18039/com.radioafrica.music D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x65dd2f78>
11-19 15:53:40.787 18039-18051/com.radioafrica.music E/MediaPlayer: error (262, 0)
11-19 15:53:40.790 18039-18039/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(100, 262, 0)
11-19 15:53:40.790 18039-18039/com.radioafrica.music E/MediaPlayer: Error (262,0)
11-19 15:53:40.810 18039-18050/com.radioafrica.music E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
11-19 15:53:40.836 18039-18039/com.radioafrica.music E/Music: Error: what=262, extra=0
```

when i try playing m4a files using media player but I can seem to get what `Error (262,0)` or `error (1, -2147483648)` mean.